# PHP works on some files but not others

Tags: php, wordpress

The coding to my wordpress site just decides when it wants to work or not if anyone has any ideas on why or how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

```
http://www.gallatinchurchofchrist.com/sermons-2
```

Sermon on line 1 just shows the code but the exact same one on line 5 comes with audio bar. The Others Show absolutely NOTHING.... I've been trying to figure this out for a couple days now and still no luck.

```
<?php 
global $ichthys_redux;


$placeholder = '700x450';
$thumbnail_class = 'vc_col-md-5';
$post_details_class = 'vc_col-md-7';
$image_size = 'ichthys_post_pic700x450';

//Meta boxes
$sermon_mp3 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ichthys_sermon_mp3', TRUE );
$sermon_youtube = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ichthys_sermon_youtube', TRUE );
$sermon_vimeo = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ichthys_sermon_vimeo', TRUE );
$sermon_background = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ichthys_sermon_bg_color', TRUE );
$sermon_list_view_option = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ichthys_sermon_list_view_option', TRUE );
?>

<article  id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('row'); ?> >    
    <div class="item vc_col-md-12 high-padding"  >
        <div class="container sermon_content" >
            <div class="vc_col-md-9" >
                <h2 class="sermon_title">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID);?></a>
                </h2>
                <ul class="sermon_icons">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php echo get_the_date( "F j, Y" ); ?></a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?php echo get_the_author(); ?></li>
                    <li class="taxonomy-list">
                        <i class="fa fa-book"></i> 
                        <?php $taxonomies = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'sermons' );
                        if ($taxonomies) { ?>
                                <?php foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) { ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr($taxonomy->name); ?><span>,</span></a>
                                <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> <?php echo get_comments(array('post_id' => $post->ID,'count' => TRUE)) . esc_attr__(' Comments','ichthys'); ?></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="sermon_song">

                    <?php 
                        if($sermon_list_view_option=='option_audio'){
                            echo do_shortcode("<p>[audio src=".esc_attr($sermon_mp3)."]</p>");
                        }elseif($sermon_list_view_option=='option_youtube'){
                            echo do_shortcode('<p>[vc_video link="'.esc_attr($sermon_youtube).'"]</p>');
                        }elseif($sermon_list_view_option=='option_vimeo'){
                            echo do_shortcode('<p>[vc_video link="'.esc_attr($sermon_vimeo).'"]</p>');
                        } 
                    ?>

                </div>
                <?php the_content(''); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="vc_col-md-3" >
                <div class="medium-padding sermon-links">
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" role="button"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <?php esc_attr_e('View Sermon', 'ichthys'); ?></a></p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" role="button"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> <?php esc_attr_e('Leave a comment', 'ichthys'); ?></a></p>
                    <?php if($sermon_list_view_option=='option_audio'){ ?>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo esc_attr($sermon_mp3); ?>" role="button"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> <?php esc_attr_e('Download Sermon', 'ichthys'); ?></a></p>
                    <?php }elseif($sermon_list_view_option=='option_youtube'){ ?>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo esc_attr($sermon_youtube); ?>" role="button"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> <?php esc_attr_e('Watch Video', 'ichthys'); ?></a></p>
                    <?php }elseif($sermon_list_view_option=='option_vimeo'){ ?>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo esc_attr($sermon_vimeo); ?>" role="button"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> <?php esc_attr_e('Watch Video', 'ichthys'); ?></a></p>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: holy hell that code looks like something from a horror movie... is anything printed to the error logs?

Comment: You are using the Wordpress function incorrectly.  1. You don't put html tags in `do_shortcode` 2. `the_content` can only be used in the loop and you are not in the loop. You need to use the `$post` object like you did in the rest of the code,

Answer (score 0):

This could be for some php errors!
when you disabled showing error in php, php executes code until the syntax, logic or data error! and then shows nothing.

Do these suggestions:

1. Enable error reporting for all errors, warnings and etc
2. Make logs by `var_dump($var)`
3. Test php output to get when php ends executing